# Use open telemetry in Spring boot without injecting the jar and using jvm args

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry

I am testing [opentelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/) in Spring boot and trying out if it is doable without injecting the jar file to the app and using jvm arguments, so far I tried using the following dependency in my gradle app:

```
runtimeOnly 'io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent:1.19.1'
```

and placed the the following properties in my application.properties file

```
otel.service.name=your-service-name
otel.traces.exporter=zipkin
```

but it's not working and traces are not showing in the console logs.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenTelemetry javaagent is not able to extract configuration from the Spring config file; it happens way too late after the agent initialization.

You'll need to pass these settings either as system properties, e.g.:

```bash
java -javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
     -Dotel.service.name=your-service-name \
     -Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin \
     -jar my-app.jar
```

or as environment variables:

```bash
export OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=your-service-name
export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=zipkin
java -javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -jar my-app.jar
```